# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' at ng serve

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json

For some reason, I get this error all of a sudden. It's probably a version problem with angular-cli`, but I could not find the problem. Thanks for the help!

`npm i` only shows some warnings and the compiler one is there. If I install that specific version from the peer dependency warning, another one for a different version pops up the next time I do `npm i` and the error at `ng serve` is not resolved.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/dygraphs": "^1.1.8",
    "acorn": "^6.2.1",
    "angular-material-fileupload": "^2.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.15.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "coaty": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-create": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-lib": "^9.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-zeroconf": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "dygraphs": "^2.1.0",
    "e2e": "0.0.8",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.15.0",
    "forever-agent": "^0.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "insight": "^0.10.3",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "nodejs-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "promzard": "^0.3.0",
    "read": "^1.0.7",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "spdx-exceptions": "^2.2.0",
    "spdx-expression-parse": "^3.0.0",
    "spdx-license-ids": "^3.0.5",
    "sxml": "^1.0.4",
    "tough-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "but": "^2.0.1",
    "canvas": "^2.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "conventional-changelog": "^3.1.8",
    "conventional-recommended-bump": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `^` in your dependencies versions so it will lock down to a specific version of that dependency (your working configuration). When you do `npm install` it will install the locked version. `^` means: this version or higher if available. This will cause conflicts in the future as dependencies will change quite a bit.